# C/C++ API ODBC process ID

Tags: c++, c, odbc

I would like to know if it's possible to get the current process id of an SQL connection through ODBC C/C++ API.
Under SqlServer it is @@spid, connection_id() with MySQL.
Cannot find that in ODBC documentation.

Thanks...

Comment: SQL connections don't have pids.  Do you mean the SQL server instance pid?  Or maybe the client?

Comment: I mean server instance id, the one we see after a sp_who for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a stored procedure to return @@spid on the connection

CREATE PROC
    GetSPID
AS
    SELECT @@SPID AS 'ID';

Then exec as per usual OBDC API

Comment: Yes, but stuck with SqlServer and not really portable.